# Getting error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol in vS@)!) that compiled fine in VC 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010

I am trying to compile a 14 year old C++ program with VS2010 C++ compiler (dont ask why :( ).    I am getting the following error

Error   10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CConfiguration::CConfiguration(void)" (??0CConfiguration@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function 
"public: __thiscall CWhoisService::CWhoisService(void)" (??0CWhoisService@@QAE@XZ)

I have a cpp file CWhoisService.cpp with a header CWhoisService.h

CWhoisService.h:

```
class CWhoisService
{
public:
    HRESULT Initialize(const char * szServiceName, REFCLSID pMetricsCLSID);

CWhoisService();
~CWhoisService();
HRESULT CheckService();

protected:

    CConfiguration m_Configuration;    
protected:
    bool           m_bStartedEvenLog;
    bool           m_bStartedConfiguration;

private:
       //Don't want standard constructor to be called
};
```

CWhoisService.cpp

```
#include "ConfigurationLib.h"
#include "CWhoisService.h"

CWhoisService::CWhoisService():
    m_bStartedEvenLog(false),
    m_bStartedConfiguration(false) 
{

}
HRESULT CWhoisService::Initialize(const char * szServiceName, REFCLSID pMetricsCLSID)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    //Initialize the configuration library
    hr = m_Configuration.Initialize(VERSION_COMPANY,VERSION_SYSTEM);
```

the ConfigurationLib.h file referenced in the cpp file and included before CWhoisService.h is as follows:

```
#ifndef _CONFIGURATION_MODULE
#define _CONFIGURATION_MODULE

class CConfigurationBase
{
public:
    CConfigurationBase() : m_bInitialized(false) {};
    virtual ~CConfigurationBase() {};

    virtual HRESULT Initialize(LPCTSTR szCompanyName, LPCTSTR szSystemName, LPCTSTR szGlobalMachineName = NULL) = 0;

    virtual bool IsInitialized() { return m_bInitialized;};

protected:
    bool m_bInitialized;            // True if the object has been initialized
};

class CConfiguration : public CConfigurationBase
{
public:
    CConfiguration();
    virtual ~CConfiguration();

    // Initialized some values for the class.  Must be called first!
    virtual HRESULT Initialize(LPCTSTR szCompanyName, LPCTSTR szSystemName, LPCTSTR szGlobalMachineName = NULL);

protected:
    // This is the function that actually goes about getting values from the registry
    // The other Get functions all call this one
    virtual HRESULT GetValue(HKEY hkeyBase, LPCTSTR szSectionName, LPCTSTR szValueName, CString * csValue, DWORD * pdwValue, DWORD dwType);  
}; // CConfiguration
#endif // _CONFIGURATION_MODULE
```

everything was fine last time it compiled around 10 years ago.  but now it does not seem to find the ConfigurationLib.h file.  i made sure it as part of the project.  if i removed it from the start of the cpp file I get the error: missing ';' before identifier 'm_Configuration'  so ti obviously see it.  yet it does not appear to be able to resolve the class.

Any assistance would be appreciated, i have spend last 3 days on this site and many others but no progress.

Comment: So where is the implementation of the constructor to `CConfiguration`?  That is exactly what the error is telling you.

Comment: The error message states that linker couldn't find definition of constructor for `CConfiguration`. Please, show your cpp file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i have spend last 3 days on this site and many others but no progress`

It is always good to understand the errors that are produced by the linker for Visual C++.  Then next time you see such an error, it shouldn't take 3 days to figure out.  I know the message looks garbled at first, but it really isn't if you know what to look for.

The trick is to choose the parts of the error that makes sense, and skip over the name-mangling (the gobbledy-gook that looks like the linker is swearing at you).  Sometimes the name-mangling is useful, but for your error, it isn't important.

Let's go through the error:

`unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CConfiguration::CConfiguration(void)"`

The line above indicates the function implementation that cannot be found by the linker.  The function is `CConfiguration::CConfiguration(void)`.  In other words, the 0-argument constructor for `CConfiguration` cannot be located by the linker.

Next part of the error message states:

`referenced in function "public: __thiscall CWhoisService::CWhoisService(void)"`

This is the function that is attempting to call the `CConfiguration` constructor.  It is the `CWhoisService::CWhoisService(void)` constructor.  You see it here:

```
class CWhoisService
{
  //...
protected:
     CConfiguration m_Configuration;  
};
```

You have a member that is a `CConfiguration` (m_Configuration), so when you instantiate a `CWhoIsService`, you are also instantiating a `CConfiguration` object.

The bottom line is that the linker cannot find the implementation to the `CConfiguration` constructor that takes no arguments.

Either you

1. did not add the source module to your project that contains the implementation of the `CConfiguration` constructor to the project, or
2. The `CConfiguration` constructor is in a library and you didn't specify the library to link to in your project, or
3. You just plain old didn't code a `CConfiguration` constructor that has no arguments, or
4. some other unknown issue that causes the linker to miss the code that contains the implementation of the constructor.

My guess is more than likely item `1.` above.

Also, this has nothing to do with header files.  The header file allows a module to be compiled without error.  It does *not* guarantee that the linker will link successfully.

For example, you can have a module that contains calls to functions that do not exist, but the module will compile successfully.  However, at link time, if the function called doesn't actually exist, *then* you will get the error (as you're seeing now).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It was as you deduced 1. I had not added the source module to my project.

Answer (score 1):

At least in the code snippets you showed there is no the constructor definition. It is only declared

```
class CConfiguration : public CConfigurationBase
{
public:
    CConfiguration();
//...
```